# Should I go for dedicated server to host an EJB application?

Tags: java, ejb, hosting, jboss7.x

I'm building an application that invokes a (JAVA)web service implemented in JBOSS.
I plan to host the web service as soon as I finish building it.
My question is: Should I go for a dedicated server to host it? Or go for a VPS?
I read about this two hosting possibilities but did not find a clear answer for my case.
Thank you.

Comment: "I have a video game; what computer do I need to run it?". That's effectively what you just asked. It would literally be impossible to answer without additional details on what your service is, what it does, the resources it will require, and what supporting systems are required. That said, it's probably going to be off-topic for SO at that point, and better asked on serverfault or superuser.

Comment: @BrianRoach: I believe that the question is so basic, and I needed a so basic answer too, because this is my first experience in "hosting" and I already found many answers by googling, however, needed to know if I go for a VPS or dedicated server to just host an EJB web service. LCR gave me a basic answer that it answered my question;

Comment: Unfortunately, he gave you a *bad answer* as it's based on absolutely nothing other than his inexperience. But, it's your money ::shrug::

Comment: @BrianRoach: It'll be absolutely useful if you post useful answers. To answer your question: as you know a web service doesn't need so much powerful resources, and as you know, JBOSS is multi platform, so it's better to go with Unix based server in that case because it's cheaper. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Erm, choosing a dedicated server vs. VPS has nothing to do with what OS you put on it. All my dev work and side projects I do on a $17/mo Ubuntu VPS from Rackspace. I'm attempting to give you useful comments, you're just ignoring them based on a pre-conceived notion of what you need and a lack of understanding of *why* you would want a dedicated server versus a VPS.

Comment: @BrianRoach Okay, if I reformulate my question: what is the best option to choose between VPS or dedicated web server when wanting to host not too much powerful web service? The advantage of dedicated server is that you have your own machine(with all its hardware capabilities) , you install what you want on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am hosting a web service on a dedicated server with Rackspace. It works well, and I can always add their hybrid solution in the future if I want.

I went with their dedicated server, because I have full control. Their support team is awesome and their machines are pretty good.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's my first experience with hosting so that's why I asked, I already called them but felt that they just want more money and do not give advice! I'll go for a dedicated server so, I just want a full control and a whole machine for my web service. Thank you.

Comment: andronienn no problem. I have installed several applications on their hardware, and it is the same as the servers we host within our company. You will have full control to the hardware, which is nice when you have to install anything